# Using Linux C++ shared and static libraries in a same program

Tags: c++, linux, static, shared

How can I use both C++ shared and static libraries in a same Linux program?

When managing with g++, I've tried to arrange `-static` command ahead and behind the libraries I don't want to link statically, but with no results. `ld` through `g++` complains about where are the .a files of the shared libraries (*cannot find -lwhatever* error).

**EDIT**: the problem isn't the *cannot find -lwhatever* error, since it just happens because there isn't static version of the specified library. What I'm trying to do is to specify which libraries are to be statically linked and which are to be dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming a static `libfoo.a` and a dynamic `libbar.so` you could use

```
g++ -o prog main.o other.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lfoo -Wl,-Bdynamic -lbar
```

<sup>You should avoid calling functions in a static library from a dynamic one; this would be ugly.</sup>

#### hint

The `-Wl` options to `g++` are used to pass arguments to the `ld` linker invoked by `g++`.

You may want to use `g++ -v` to understand how `g++` invokes `ld`, and you could also use `g++ -v -Wl,--verbose`  to also ask `ld` to be verbose.

Comment: OK, so you are forcing it to look for the static or dynamic version of some lib. But if you only have a static version of foo and a dynamic version of bar. Do you really need to specify static/dynamic??

Comment: I think your answer is addressing the issue. When I use your parameters it looks `ld` accepts them but further I got the error `cannot find -lgcc_s`. Then, I add the `-static-libgcc` flag and I got the error `dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp with pointer equality in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie` Any suggestion? I'm investigating on this.

Comment: Ups, in this case I think `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic` have no effect, those commands are only for VxWorks: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/gcc/VxWorks-Options.html. On my project nothing happens with or without them.

Comment: I wrote `-Wl,-Bstatic` which passes `-Bstatic` to `ld`, so should have some effect (and also works on x86). Use `g++ -v` to understand how `ld` is run by `gcc`, and use `g++ -v -Wl,--verbose` to understand what `ld` is doing.

Comment: Thanks Basile, you were absolutely right. My question was too much newbie. But your feedback has been very useful for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to specify -static or -dynamic. The format of the file you link with specify if it is a shared or a static link. You just need to choose the correct file to link with.

Comment: OK, I reading little bit to fast, you mean both static and shared libstdc++ ??